# How to pass 'window' JSObject from one browser to another?

Tags: javafx, webview, jxbrowser, jsobject

With JavaFx WebView, I can get the 'window' of a browser instance[1] with:

```
// Java code
netscape.javascript.JSObject win = (JSObject) webengine.executeScript("window");
```

Then I can pass this JSObject to another browser instance[2], and in this browser's javascript, I can manipulate and access DOM, variables and functions of the first browser instance[1] like this:

```
// Javascript code
// get 'window' netscape.javascript.JSObject of 'browser1' webview 
// control from the getWindow() method in my linked Java class
var window1 = javaObj.getWindow("browser1");

// get variables defined in 'browser1' javascript
var rString = window1.myString;
var rNum = window1.myNumber;

// execute the 'myAlert' function on 'browser1' and pass variables in
window1.myAlert(rString + " - " + rNum + "<br><br>" + Date());

// manipulate the DOM on 'browser1'
window1.document.getElementById("myLabel").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

How can I achieve this with jxBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser provides similar functionality that allows injecting Java objects into JavaScript and call its methods from JavaScript code, but JxBrowser doesn't use the `netscape.javascript.JSObject` class. The following example demonstrates the idea how to use the Java object injection to access Java object methods from JavaScript:

```java
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSValue;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.By;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.DOMDocument;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.dom.DOMElement;

public class JavaScriptJavaSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();

        JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");

        // Inject Java object into JavaScript and associate it with
        // the window.javaWindow property.
        JavaWindow javaWindow = new JavaWindow(browser);
        window.asObject().setProperty("javaWindow", javaWindow);

        // You can access public fields of the injected Java object
        // and modify their values from JavaScript. For example:
        //
        // window.javaWindow.myString = 'Hello, Java';
        // window.javaWindow.myNumber = 123;
        // window.document().getElementById('myLabel').setAttribute('name', 'myName');
    }

    public static class JavaDocument {

        private DOMDocument document;

        public JavaDocument(DOMDocument document) {
            this.document = document;
        }

        public DOMElement getElementById(String id) {
            return document.findElement(By.id(id));
        }
    }

    public static class JavaWindow {
        public String myString;
        public int myNumber;

        private Browser browser;

        public JavaWindow(Browser browser) {
            this.browser = browser;
        }

        public JavaDocument document() {
            return new JavaDocument(browser.getDocument());
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about JavaScript-Java Bridge API in the articles at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/folders/9000074803